# Using OrderBy and ToArray to list objects in C# in alphabetical order

Tags: c#, sorting, asp.net-mvc-5, sql-order-by, toarray

I'm working on a web page that displays a list of objects, but they are displayed in a completely random and jumbled up manner. I'm trying to make them show up in alphabetical order.

The code I have so far for this is:

```
public ActionResult Listing(string id)
{
    List<MediaListingPreviewModel> models = null;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
    {
        var ids = id.Split(new char[] { ',', '&' }).Select(n => new Guid(n)).ToArray();
        if (ids.Length > 0)
        {
            models = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<MediaListingPreviewModel>>(RetrieveRepository<MediaSpace>().GetMany(n => ids.Contains(n.Id))).ToList();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        models = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<MediaListingPreviewModel>>(RetrieveRepository<MediaSpace>().GetMany(n => n.Deleted == false && n.Placements.Where(p => p.Deleted == false).Count() > 0)).ToList();
    }

    if (models.Count() < 5)
    {
        var currentCount = models.Count();
        while (currentCount < 5)
        {
            var model = new MediaListingPreviewModel();
            models.Add(model);
            currentCount++;
        }
    }
    return View(models.Take(models.Count).OrderBy(model => model.Name).ToArray());
}
```

I've tried modifying the return statement a few times, such as using `OrderByDescending(model => model)` but it doesn't work (I get a 404 error on the page supposed to display the list).

Comment: `404` error have nothing to do with `OrderBy` and `ToArray`. It means your view is not found.

Comment: You might need to explicitely mention viewname View("ViewName", models.Take(models.Count).OrderBy(model => model.Name).ToArray());

Comment: What model does you view require a List or an Array?